# PHP PayPal API Express CheckOut

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate PayPal Express Checkout using PayPal Payment REST API. I want our clients to allow their user to pay using PayPal Express Checkout.

I dont see any documentation on their site explaining about how to integrate express checkout using their user API **Username, Password and Signature**, instead using Oauth credential Client ID/Token.

Do i have to use adaptive payment method?

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment

```
$paypal_context = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential('client-id', 'client-token')
);

// $paypal_context->setConfig(
//  array(
//      'mode' => 'sandbox',
//      'acct.UserName' => '',
//      'acct.Password' => '',
//      'acct.Signature'    => ''
//  )
// );
// OR
//$paypal_context = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
//  array(
//      'mode' => 'sandbox',
//      'acct1.UserName'    => '',
//      'acct1.Password'    => '',
//      'acct1.Signature'   => ''
//  )
//);

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();

$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
...
$payment->create($paypal_context);

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Started with Express Checkout, plz refer to [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).